# Can I leave Abu Dhabi airport while on a transit?

Tags: transit, pakistani-citizens, abu-dhabi, etihad

I am traveling from Pakistan to Bangkok on Etihad Airways. I have a transit at Abu Dhabi of 12 hours. Can I go out of the airport to spend the time in Abu Dhabi? I am holding a Pakistani passport. It will be my first trip so, I am not sure what are the rules and regulation.

Answer (score 6):

You can leave the airport only with a Transit Visa. Refer to these links

http://www.abudhabiairport.ae/english/airport-information/transit-information/more-than-4-hours.aspx

http://www.abudhabiairport.ae/english/airport-information/check-in-and-passport-control/immigration-and-visas.aspx

Also, Etihad airways is also providing for transit visa. Refer to this website for more details. I think its best to consult the airline website in these cases.

https://www.ttsuaevisas.com/en/global/visa-fees/